# Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN

Tags: php, php-curl

If i use the `CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN` option in my code , then i get the following error.

> Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN - assumed
>   'CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN'

The CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN is a supported option in php 7.4.5 [interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) .

php -v

```
PHP 7.4.5 (cli) (built: Apr 14 2020 12:54:33) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.5, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

curl -V

```
curl 7.70.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.70.0 NSS/3.44 zlib/1.2.7 libpsl/0.7.0 (+libicu/50.1.2) libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.31.1
Release-Date: 2020-04-29
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz Metalink NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL UnixSockets
```

What am i doing wrong here ?

Edit 1:

Here are additional info corresponding to YouriKoeman's overview

Kernel version : 3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64

OS : unix (Centos 7.x)

`curl --tcp-fastopen -L http://www.google.com` return the following error:

`curl: (55) Send failure: Operation not supported for curl --tcp-fastopen -L http://www.google.com`

Comment: Sorry - just have to check if it's enabled - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713591/use-of-undefined-constant-curlopt-post-assumed-curlopt-post

Comment: @NigelRen the curl extension is enable.I can make curl request just fine , only this option is causing issues

Comment: Could you please share the result of this command: `php -r 'print_r(curl_version()['version']);'`

Comment: I am getting `PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant version - assumed 'version' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in Command line code on line 1` with your command

Comment: @0stone0 here is a part of phpinfo  for curl- https://i.gyazo.com/710f2787f38aa4a6438612fdc9b3ac20.png

Comment: There should be a version number behind the undefined constant

Comment: @0stone0 you were right i missed the full part `PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant version - assumed 'version' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in Command line code on line 1
7.70.0`

Comment: Are you by any chance testing the code on windows? it is only supported on unix type operating systems.

Comment: @YouriKoeman i am on centos 7

Comment: @user2650277 I have updated my answer with some comments, hope they help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was that tcp fast open is not enabled by default until kernel version 3.13.

To enable TCP Fast Open on Centos 7:

1.Add tcp_fastopen in sysctl.d

```
echo "net.ipv4.tcp_fastopen=3" > /etc/sysctl.d/30-tcp_fastopen.conf
```

2.Restart sysctl

```
systemctl restart systemd-sysctl
```

3.Verify sysctl setup for tcp_fastopen

`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fastopen` should output 3

Comment: I didn't know it was off by default (i run a rolling release distro). Good find! glad it's fixed

Answer (score 9):

> I chose to answer in a more broad way to hopefully help more poeple when they encounter issues relating to this and google for answers

**(Note: php runtime and Loaded extensions can differ between the CLI and when accessed from a webserver)**.

## What are the system requirements for this feature?

The feature `CURLOPT_TCP_FASTOPEN` you want to use has some system requirements that have to be met

They are the following:

1. You must have `Kernel version > 3.6 (linux)`
2. You must have `PHP 7.0.7` or higher
3. You must have `Curl(program) AND php{your/version}-curl 7.49.0` or higher
4. You must have a `*nix` type of operating system (macos, linux, bsd)

## how to debug What requirement is not being met?

The fact that the constant is not defined is a red flag that one of these dependencies is not met, but how do i figure out which?

### kernel version

This one is easy, run the following command:
`uname -r`.

It must be greater than `3.6`

### Curl version and build options

The best way to check if the functionality is available in curl is to call curl from the cli with this option, like:
`curl --tcp-fastopen -O http://google.com`

If this request goes successfully, curl is configured correctly on your system, so the problem lies within php

### PHP version and extensions

#### For webserver

use `phpinfo()` to check if the `php version` is greater than `7.0.7` And that the `php-curl` extensions are loaded

#### For CLI

in the command line type `php -v` the version should be greater than `7.0.7`.

To check the extensions type the following into your command line `php -m | grep curl` this command should return `curl`, if nothing is returned the curl extension is not loaded for the php cli.

Comment: Thanks for the detaiiled answer.I am getting the following error.`curl: (55) Send failure: Operation not supported` for `curl --tcp-fastopen  -L http://www.google.com` . There might be something missing in the build options for curl

Comment: You can install a curl binary with this build option from a custom repo, which one i dont's know for redhat sadly. the option i know for sure that will work is building curl yourself with said build option

Comment: Ps: this might also mean that your kernel version is not up to date (needs to support `send()` networking command). is your kernel version > 3.6 (Above 3.6, not 3.6 itself)

Comment: run the following commands to make sure you are up to date as far as the official (or your custom) repos can provide: `yum -y update kernel`  `yum remove curl` `yum install curl`